# The webview does not match the content

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

The webview does not match the content, I put webView.scalesPageToFit = YES, and continues to be nothing wrong in vertical, horizontal clear if it shows well,I leave the image shows that it cuts down the webview

[image]

Comment: Where are you putting the scalesPageToFit ?

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Should do the trick, note: it won't always work if the website contained in the webView prevents it somehow. If you edit your post to include the link you're trying to display, perhaps we can help you debug it further.